# OnItemClick Listener not responding to action

Tags: android

I have two AutoComplete widget on which i have registered setOnItemClickListener like this

```
productTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.prodName_CB)
productTextView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

supplierTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.supplierName_CB);
supplierTextView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos, long rowId) {
    Log.d("-----", "listener");
    if (view.getId() == R.id.supplierName_CB) {
        Log.d("-----", "inside Supplier wigdet");
        loadFilteredProducts(supplierTextView.getText().toString());
    }
    else if(view.getId() == R.id.prodName_CB)
    {
        //getSupplierName(productTextView.getText().toString());
        Log.d("-----", "inside Product wigdet");
    }
}
```

i see the Log.d message for the Log.d("-----", "listener") but i dont get into the if/else.what is wrong in my code.

Comment: add android:onclick attribute to autocomplete textviews in your xml file and write the action in your java file.

Comment: May be both of your conditions would be failing, instead of this  Log.d("-----", "listener");
you can Log some thing like this Log.d("-----", view.getId()); and check it

Comment: @rajesh.adhi 

`og.d("-----view", " "+view.getId());`
`Log.d("-----adapter", " "+adapter.getId());`

08-30 10:32:46.039: D/-----view(6804):  16908308
08-30 10:32:46.039: D/-----adapter(6804):  -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Use Separate setOnItemClickListener for both AutoCompleteTextView.

```
 productTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
 {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
      {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
 });

 supplierTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
 {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
      {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
 });
```

Comment: where w2ill i place this code in the onCreate(). if yes,then it will make my code very messy.since my onCreate method now is long enough

Comment: in OnCreate() Make one Function like initControls(); and put all code in it.

Comment: your code works but why is it not working my way.what is the deal.can you point out.the weird thing is that when i print the 
Log.d("-----view", " "+arg1.getId());
Log.d("-----adapter", " "+arg0.getId()); 

for both the listner it is printing out 

08-30 10:40:05.618: D/-----view  16908308
08-30 10:40:05.618: D/-----adapter  -1

Answer (score 0):

You should use AdapterView.getId() not View.getId().

Cause View is the child of AutoCompleteTextView, not AutoCompleteTextView. So change onItemClick to following:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos, long rowId) {
    Log.d("-----", "listener");
    if (adapter.getId() == R.id.supplierName_CB) {
        Log.d("-----", "inside Supplier wigdet");
        loadFilteredProducts(supplierTextView.getText().toString());
    }
    else if(adapter.getId() == R.id.prodName_CB)
    {
        //getSupplierName(productTextView.getText().toString());
        Log.d("-----", "inside Product wigdet");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `adapter.getChildAt(position).getId()` instead of `adapter.getId()` or `view`.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this thread after searching for the same problem but came up with my own solution after some trial and error.

I have two listviews, one is a custom list view and the other one is just a standards multiple item click.

My implementation catches both events by using the parent

```
ListView obj1List;
List<Object1> selectedObject1s = new ArrayList<Object1>();
ListView obj2List;
List<Object2> selectedObject2s = new ArrayList<Object2();
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    switch (parent.getId()) {
    case R.id.obj1_list:
        Object1 obj1 = (Object1) obj1List.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) view;
        if (ctv.isChecked()) {
            ctv.setChecked(false);
            selectedObject1s.remove(obj1);
        } else {
            ctv.setChecked(true);
            selectedObject1s.add(obj1);
        }
        break;
    // This catches the custom ListView w/ custom row cb_row_checked
    case R.id.obj2_list:
        Obj2 obj2 = ((Obj2ListAdapter) obj2List.getAdapter()).getItem(position);
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb_row_checked);
        if (cb.isChecked()) {
            cb.setChecked(false);
            selectedObj2s.remove(obj2);
        } else {
            cb.setChecked(true);
            selectedObj2s.add(obj2);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```